# pg_dump segmentation fault with postgresql 13

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 18.04 I'm running postgresql 12 server but the client tools were just upgraded to 13. When I run pg_dump with --exclude-schema=public I get "segmentation fault (core dumped)". My full pg_dump statement:

```
pg_dump -Fc --exclude-schema=public -f "../$PGDATABASE.backup"
```

Removing --exclude-schema=public I do not get the segmentation fault. I'm using the apt.postgresql.org repo, not the default Ubuntu repo. Postgres 13 was installed automatically with a recent `apt upgrade`. After which I did `apt remove postgresql-13` becasue I don't want to upgrade to 13. This removed the postgres server but not the client tools.

Comment: Maybe more relevant at https://dba.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Can't you just remove the Postgres 13 client tools as well? If you don't use Postgres 13, you don't need them.

Comment: Remove the PostgreSQL v13 client package as well.

Comment: I cannot replicate this. What does pg_dump --version show? Also output of pg_lsclusters?

Comment: As suggested by  a_horse_with_no_name and  Laurenz Albe I will try removing the client tools outside of business hours. I should have thought of this myself although I have had differing version of server and client tools installed in previous configurations without issues.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver pg_dump --version 12.4 and pg_lsclusters too long to paste into comment but I think if I clean up my installed versions I'll be okay. Thanks.

Comment: Well if you have not removed the Postgres 13 client tools, then this odd. Without using `--cluster=` the `pg_dump` version should be the latest, 13. Are you sure you do not have Postgres packages from the Ubuntu repo in the mix?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver All installed postgres packages say "/bionic-pgdg" which I believe indicates that I do not have any from the Ubuntu repo.

Comment: Do you still have the 13 clients installed? Also what does whereis pg_dump show? This issue has the hallmarks of a mixed library problem.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver Indeed it does look to be a mixed library problem. I don't want to mess with it during my peak load hours. Will work on it tonight and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223385/discussion-between-richard-greenwood-and-adrian-klaver).